# Mongoose model not recognizing all properties

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am running into an issue where my mongoose model does not seem to recognize all the properties assigned to it when hydrated with data from the db. I am simply trying to access the "make" property of the objects I imported from a CSV.

Model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  model: String,
  make: String,
  keyType: String,
  years: String,
  rsType: String,
  activeRemotesFobs: String,
  partNumber: String,
  cost: String
})
const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
module.exports = Product;
```

Query to fetch all rows:

```
exports.index = (req, res) => {
  Product.find({}, function(err, products){
    console.log(products[0])
    console.log(products[0].make)
    res.json(products)
  })
};
```

And the output from that query:

```
{ _id: 5a7f2bf4dd2ee45983440017,
'make': 'TOYOTA',
model: 'RAV4',
keyType: 'STEEL (G/H) KEY',
years: '2011-2018',
rsType: 'RS ONLY W/FACT. REMOTES + APP',
activeRremotesFobs: 'FACT. REMOTES ONLY & APP',
partNumber: 'FLRSBA/ASCL6',
cost: '$719' }
undefined
```

So, clearly there is something different about 'make', as I cannot access that property. All the other properties are easily accessible. I imported this using mongoimport, with a headerline that matches my properties. Here is a screenshot of the same record using robomongo, a GUI for mongodb

[image: Record in robomongo]

Any help would be appreciated. I have tried renaming the column, changing the order in my schema, and re-importing the records many times with no luck.

Comment: Do you actually call `mongoose.model` twice and set `module.exports` twice, or is that a copy/paste error on your post here?

Comment: also, what's the output of `products[0]['make']` ?

Comment: @Paul, thats a copy/paste error.. editing now

Comment: @Paul - the output is undefined. Outputting any other property in that object works fine.

Comment: I just did this and could not repeat your problem.  I created  a schema identical to yours, saved a product, then pulled it back and consoled it out in the same way, and `products[0].make` consoled out as Toyota.  Are you on the latest version of everything?  See if you can repeat the problem in another schema file with a different name.

Comment: You mentioned using mongoimport to get the data in; was the original data inserted using mongoose? I can't help but wonder if that's what "broke" that field somehow (though I can't think of how, it should be a simple mapping of field names)

Comment: The original data was imported using the bundled command line tool that Mongo ships for importing csv's. So, no the data was not inserted using mongoose. Thank you for testing that out, the problem must lie in the import somewhere. I'll hammer on that a bit and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: @Paul - Updating Mongo from 3.2 (Its been a while since I last updated) to 3.4 and then 3.6 fixed it. Not sure what the ultimate problem was... Thanks again for your help

Comment: Ah, if you just started the project then it’s probab a version mismatch between the latest version of Mongoose and an older version of mongo

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem many times and I found a workaround to this . You can create a new Object and assign it to the result of query (here products[0]) and then you can access all properties of the second object .

Like

```
exports.index = (req, res) => {
    Product.find({}, function(err, products){
    const Product2 = Object.assign({},products[0]);
    console.log(product2)
    console.log(product2._doc.make)
   res.json(products)
  })
};
```

Comment: This might work, but doesn't address the problem.  His issue is not repeatable on a different machine, therefore it's not inherently a mongoose/mongodb limitation.

Comment: @Paul I have explicitly mentioned that this is a workaround for this type of problem .I still can't figure out the main reason behind these types of problem.

Comment: Interestingly, this workaround does not work for me. I still see single quotes around the 'make' key and its still inaccessible. I suspect Paul was on the right track in the comments above with something going haywire in the import.

Comment: @sottenad Sorry I had made a typo and didn't write '_doc' try this once

Comment: Thanks @Shiv, it turns out upgrading Mongo to the latest stable version fixed this. I appreciate your help